# Defining Legendre polynomials in terms of a sinusoidal function for $|x| \leq 1$

Tags: polynomials, special-functions, orthogonal-polynomials, legendre-polynomials

Would it be possible to define Legendre polynomials in terms of a sinusoidal function for $|x|\leq 1$ in a similar manner to Chebyshev polynomials being defined as $T_n(x) = \cos(n \cos^{-1}(x))$?

Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Define  "similar manner".

Answer (score 1):

No doubt that $x=\cos\theta$ is a meaningful substitution for the Legendre polynomials. The functions $P_n(\cos\theta)$ were already considered by Legendre in the [spherical harmonic expansion of the Newton potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials#Expanding_a_1/r_potential).
However, the substitution is not so happy as for the Chebyshev polynomials. Here below is what you get from the generating function of the Legendre's polynomials -not bad after all, but there may be something better.
$$P_n(\cos\theta)=4^{-n}\sum_{k=0}^n{2k \choose k}{2n-2k\choose n-k}\cos\big((2n-k)\theta\big).$$

Comment: So the above identity can be written as  $$P_n = 4^{-n}\sum_{k=0}^n{2k \choose k}{2n-2k\choose n-k}T_{2n-k} $$ which has to be for sure well-known, although I do not find it around right now